# Text missing when exporting a plot as .pdf

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

I have Mathematica 13.1 on Windows 10. **The problem is not present on Mathematica 12.1!**

I try to export the following plot:

```
plot = Show[
  ListLogLogPlot[{Table[{x, 10^-12}, {x, 0.1, 5, 1}]}, Joined -> True,
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Gray}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(S\)]\) [GeV]" , 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 23], ImageSize -> Large, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.2, 5}, {10^-14, 10^-4}}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"Caption "}], 18, Black], 
   Filling -> {1 -> {True, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.3]]}}], 
  Graphics[{Text[Style["Excluded", 24, Black], Scaled[{0.2, 0.9}]], 
    Text[Style[Row[{"\[Tau] = 1 ps"}], 15, Lighter@Gray], 
     Scaled[{0.6, 0.74}], Left, {3, -0.4}], 
    Text[Style["\[Tau] = 100 ps", 15, Lighter@Gray], 
     Scaled[{0.6, 0.53}], Left, {3, -0.4}], 
    Text[Style["\[Tau] = \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\) ps", 
      15, Lighter@Gray], Scaled[{0.6, 0.34}], Left, {3, -0.4}], 
    Text[Style["\[Tau]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\) ps", 15, 
      Lighter@Gray], Scaled[{0.6, 0.15}], Left, {3, -0.4}]}]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "plot.pdf"}], plot]
```

This is how it looks in Mathematica (left) and when opening the exported .pdf (right):

[image]

In particular, all the graphics with rotated text is not present. Could you please tell me how to fix this issue?

**Edit**

The problem is in the text rotation. Say, for

```
Text[Style["\[Tau] = \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\) ps", 
      15, Lighter@Gray], Scaled[{0.6, 0.34}], Left, {3, -0.4}]
```

the text is displayed properly if removing `Left, {3, -0.4}`. However, the rotation is crucial for me.

Comment: The offending command is the  direction vector. According to the help, there are only -1,0,1 allowed.

Comment: @DanielHuber : is there any alternative to the rotation that I use?

Comment: @DanielHuber : also, it is interesting that it works on 12.1.

Comment: An alternative is Rotate[Text[...], phi], where Text is without the direction vector and the position needs adjusting.

Comment: Following up on the first comment of @DanielHuber, changing the direction vector to {1,-1} gives a plausible approximation of your goal.  (Mma's restriction on the direction vector is very curious!)

Comment: (1) I cannot reproduce the problem in V13.3 on a Mac. The PDF looks like the graphics. I wonder if it's a problem on Linux or only on Windows. (2) The direction vector can be any nonzero vector. See, for example, the "Neat Examples" section of the docs. However, `Export` may treat oblique angles in a different way than it does horizontal/vertical. I don't see why it should in PDF/PostScript/vector graphics.

Comment: What happens if you take a roundabout path?: `Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "plot.pdf"}], Import[Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "plot.svg"}], plot]]]`

Comment: It's weird.. I tried to used the string "test" instead of "\Tau = 100 ps" made the font larger and then it shows the string. Seems to me as a bug somewhere.
Text[Style["test", 25, Lighter@Gray], 
 Scaled[{0.6, 0.53}], Left, {3, -0.4}] e.g. shows in the PDF

Comment: It doesn't work. I have other plots with the same issue.
Even 
plot = Graphics[{LightGray, Rectangle[], 
   Text[Style["\[Tau] = 1 ps", 15, Lighter@Gray], Scaled[{0.6, 0.74}],
     Automatic, {0.5, -0.2}]}]
f2 = Export["plot.pdf", plot]
Import[f2]
doesn't work. (Instead of Text also tried Inset and Rotate with Text etc)

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple workaround. One can first rasterize the image:

```
plotRast = Rasterize[plot, RasterSize -> 800, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Now play with the `RasterSize` value to achieve the desired quality and export the rasterized file exactly as you did. The obtained PDF file is shown in the image below:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, but then there is no difference as compared to exporting in .png. I would like to preserve the vector form.